# Sequential search python only outputting 1 name

Tags: python

I want to go through each name in list1 and sequentially search list2 to find that name, if that name exists in list 2 as well. I ran my code with my test and it outputted only 'Bob' but it should have outputted 'Harry' as well because he is also in list2?

```
def sequential_search(list1, list2):
pos = 0
found = False


for name in list1:

    while pos < len(list2) and not found:
        if list2[pos] == name:
            found = True
            print(pos, name)
        else:
            pos = pos+1
    return found

list1 = ['Bob', 'Harry']
list2 = ['Lee', 'Bob', 'Harry']
print(sequential_search(list1, list2))
```

The output I get:
`1 Bob`

The output I should get:

1 Bob

2 Harry

(the numbers being the position in list 2 that they are in)

Comment: The `return` statement ends the entire function…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one out:

```
def sequential_search(list1, list2):
    found = False
    for pos, n1 in enumerate(list1,1):
        for n2 in list2:
            if n1 == n2:
                found = True
                print(pos, n1)
    return found

list1 = ['Bob', 'Harry']
list2 = ['Lee', 'Bob', 'Harry']
print(sequential_search(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `return` statement ends the function you never get  to the second item in the list.
I would create an array and add the elements in the loop, then you return the array.

```
output = []

for name in list1:

    #your logic

    output.append(found)

return output
```